# Literal Type Class in C++11/C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, types, c++14, literals

```
int x = 1; // Not Constant

class A {
    public:
        int value  = x;
        int value2 { x };
        A( int a )        : value( x ), value2( x ) {}
        A( int a, int b ) : value{ x }, value2{ x } {}
        constexpr A() : value{ 0 }, value2{ 0 } {}
};

constexpr int function( A obj1, A obj2, A obj3, A obj4, A obj5, A obj6, A obj7 ){ 
    return 1; 
}

int main(){

    int y = 2; // Not Constant
    A obj1   ( y );
    A obj2   { y };
    A obj3 =   y  ;
    A obj4 = { y };
    A obj5   ( y, y );
    A obj6   { y, y );
    A obj7 = { y, y };
    int var = function( obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7 );

    return 0;
}
```

C++11 Standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011), Section 3.9, Paragraph 10 states (emphasis mine):

> A type is a *literal type* if it is:
>
> - a scalar type; or
> - a reference type; or
> - a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties:
>
>   - it has a trivial destructor,
>   - **every constructor call and full-expression in the *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (if any) is a constant expression (5.19),**
>   - it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move constructor, and
>   - it has all non-static data members and base classes of literal types; or
> - an array of literal type.

In my opinion, taking into account the bullet in bold, `class A` is not a literal type in C++11 because there are constructor calls and a brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members that are not constant expressions. I tried putting `constexpr` before the constructor definition and also assigning the constructor call to a `constexpr` variable to check that indeed the compiler complains because those are not constant expressions. However, both Clang and GCC compile it successfully. So I am probably wrong.

- Does anyone know why `class A` is a literal type?

The bullet in bold was removed in C++14 ([N3652](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html)), so I understand `class A` is a literal type in C++14. I need to know because `function` is `constexpr`, therefore `each of its parameter types shall be a literal type` (C++11/C++14 Standard, Section 7.1.15, Paragraph 3).

**EDIT:** In the Original Post I used a simple example to make it easier to read, and explained I already tried many combinations. Now I updated the example with some of those combinations to show I tried different constructor calls, definitions and non-static data member initializations. Thanks.

Comment: "*Does anyone know why class A is a literal type?*" It isn't in C++11. And none of the code you've shown *requires* it to be a literal type. So what's the problem?

Comment: Do you know what a *brace-or-equal-initializer* is?

Comment: @T.C. I think *brace-or-equal initializer* is this `int x {y}` or this `int x = y`. I usually say *member-initializer-list* for the initializations in the constructor like when initializing `value` in `A( int z ) : value( x ) {}`, but I have also read a lot of people referring this like *brace-or-equal initializer*. Please correct me if I made any mistake. In any case, I tried many combinations of braces, equals, etc. initializations both for the object itself and for the variable `value` in the constructor, and the result is the same. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolBolas Section 7.1.15, Paragraph 3 of the C++11 and C++14 Standard states, referring to a `constexpr` function that `each of its parameter types shall be a literal type`. That is where it is required in `constexpr int function( A obj ){ return 1; }`. The problem is that both you and me think `class A` is not a literal type, but both Clang and GCC compile it like it is. So maybe we are missing something. Thanks.

Comment: @JL: But that line is commented out, so compilation should not be affected. So you should probably un-comment that line.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know, I commented it because it was not the main question and to make more easy the code to read. My main question is if `class A` is a literal type and why. But I will uncomment that code too. Thanks

Comment: [Core issue 1361](http://wg21.link/cwg1361). ["We resolve DR1361 by ignoring the second bullet."](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/fe32c6a33461a8c60e18c0414d4844a47442328a/lib/AST/Type.cpp#L2239)

Comment: @T.C. Thanks a lot for those links. So it seems they removed it because it "is mostly redundant with the constexpr constructor requirements in 7.1.5 [dcl.constexpr] paragraph 4". However, those requirements do not say anything about constructor calls or non-static data members being initialized with constant expressions (the requirement is just to be initialized). And that is the reason why they added the line in the first place: see [1219](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3236.html#1219). This is not clear to me, I still think my code should not be allowed in C++11.

Comment: "the requirement is just to be initialized" Read [dcl.constexpr]/4 again, especially the last three bullet points. You are also reading the quoted bullet wrong; "in the brace-or-equal-initializers" modifies both "constructor call" and "full-expression". Whether a type is a literal type has nothing to do with how variables of that type are constructed elsewhere in the program. In the end, the restriction was pointless: why should a DMI that is not actually used make a class non-literal?

Comment: @T.C. You are right, everything you say makes a lot of sense, so I guess I just did not understand the bullet in bold (3.9/10). I also read what you told me but I do not see what the relationship is with my example: I have two constructors that are not `constexpr`, so they do not have to comply with those rules for `constexpr` constructors. In any case, my program is working, so no problem, I was just curious because I like to learn. Many thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does anyone know why class `A` is a literal type?

It's not in C++11, but it is in C++14, for the reasons you cite in your post. However...

> However, both Clang and GCC compile it successfully. So I am probably wrong.

You are not wrong. Neither are clang and gcc. The code is, indeed, well-formed despite `A` not being a literal type... simply because nothing requires it to be a literal type. `function` may be a `constexpr` function, but it isn't being invoked as a constant expression. `var` isn't a `constexpr` object, so there's no enforced requirement that all the objects be of literal type. Had you tried:

```
constexpr int var = function(...);
```

*then* the code would be ill-formed, as in this case, `function(...)` would need to be a core constant expression, which requires literal types, which is a requirement that in C++11 `A` failed. (Actually, you'd also have the problem in C++14 that none of the `A`s are `constexpr` objects).